# Can we re-review this question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request, opinion-based

Not long ago, I asked the following question and got a few responses:

[How / when should a person notify in their job that they're transitioning gender?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/65684/25611)

However, it was then put on hold as being primarily opinion based.

Since then, I had changed the wording of the question to make it more fact-based, while hopefully still making it useful to more than the particular scenario I describe. Now I'd like to resubmit the question for review and hopefully it could be re-opened.

If not, I'd like to know what can I do to improve it so that it fits the standards of the site.

I'm sorry if this is not the right place, I don't exactly know how this process works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Meta is the right place to ask about specific questions, closures, reopenings, etc.

I read the current version of your question and it looks fine to me.  As you note, it's similar to many other "how do I communicate this unusual thing?" questions that we have.  It had three reopen votes already, so I've reopened.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For future reference, does the edit itself trigger the review process to reopen? If I am ever in the same situation, should I still create a meta-question?

Comment: If the question is still *on hold* (not yet *closed*), an edit triggers the review.  Feel free to ask on meta, particularly if it seems to be taking a while, or the question was somehow contentious, or you're not sure if the edit addressed people's concerns, etc.

Comment: I really appreciate the guidance and the help. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help!  I hope you get some useful answers for your friend.

Comment: @Alpha exact conditions when question edits automatically trigger reopen review are [described in this post at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773)

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as an outsider but one who has friends who have crossed the gender divide both ways, I'm not sure there is a general answer other than trying to understand the probable reactions of *individuals* in your company and deal with them on a case by case basis.

Knowing what protections you have under the law is also advisable, but alas is also a local matter right now.

Knowing local cultural tolerance also matters.

For the latter two, I think a nearby support group will give better answers than we possibly could. For the first, I think one really needs to deal with specific cases and a good answer would be too specific/extensive for us to handle here, so again I would suggest asking within the community.

It's a good question... but I don't think SE can give you the best answers. This is one to take to specialists.

Just my perceptions; I may be completely wrong.

Comment: That's good insight. However, I think the same argument could be applied to matters of sex, race, religion and nationality, and still I've seen some great answers on this site treating the subjects. I agree that they are closer to advise than an actual solution (all in all, we are still strangers on the internet) but I think that does not make it less useful.

Comment: Great answers does not mean they were good questions. The tail does not wag the dog; an exception is not a precedent. And some of these may in fact have been workspace specific enough to pass.